# FocusListener behavior

Tags: java, swing, jframe, focuslistener

I have a `JFrame` that I want closed when the user clicks off of it.  I have two `JTextFields` and a `JButton` (username, password, submit).  When I give them all the `FocusListener`, anytime the user goes from one field to another the window closes.  How can I allow the user to go from field to field and only close it if the user clicks anywhere OUT of the pop up window?

```
public class LoginForm {

    static JTextField userName;
    static JTextField password;
    static JButton submit;
    JFrame main;
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    UserSession session;

    public LoginForm(){

        Handler handle = new Handler();  //inner class
        LoginFormFocusListener fl = new LoginFormFocusListener();   //inner class

        main = new JFrame("Please Login");

        main.setUndecorated(true);
        main.setBounds((dim.width/2) - (500/2),(dim.height/2) - (150/2),500,150);
        main.setVisible(true);
        main.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        main.setResizable(false);
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        userName = new JTextField(10);
        password = new JTextField(10);
        main.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        main.add(panel);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Username: "));
        panel.add(userName);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Password: "));
        panel.add(password);

        submit = new JButton("Submit");
        panel.add(submit);

        userName.addFocusListener(fl);
        password.addFocusListener(fl);
        submit.addFocusListener(fl);

        submit.addActionListener(handle);
    }
}
```

... (unimportant methods and "Handler" class omitted)

```
public class LoginFormFocusListener implements FocusListener{

    public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
        System.out.println("focus gained...");
        System.out.println("click off of this window to close...");
    }

    public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe){
    System.out.println("focus lost...");
    WindowEvent winEvt = new WindowEvent(main, 0);
    winEvt.getWindow().dispose();
    }

}



//test
public static void main(String args[]){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){  
        public void run(){  
        new LoginForm();  
    }  
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use a FocusListener for this since these are for components that gain and lose the focus, not for top level windows. Perhaps use a WindowListener listening for the window is deactivated or iconified.

For example:

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class WindowListenerFun {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(new JTextField(10));
      panel.add(new JButton("button"));
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bad Frame");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(panel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);

      frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

         @Override
         public void windowIconified(WindowEvent wEvt) {
            ((JFrame)wEvt.getSource()).dispose();
         }

         @Override
         public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent wEvt) {
            ((JFrame)wEvt.getSource()).dispose();
         }

      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I misread your code; the other answer is correct--you need to use a WindowFocusListener instead of a FocusListener.

```
public class Listener extends WindowAdapter
{
    public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e)
    {
        Window w = e.getWindow();
        e.setVisible(false);
        e.dispose();
    }
}
```

and

`main.addWindowFocusListener(new Listener());`

**Edit2:** replaced placeholder with window closing code.

<strike>Then you add a focus listener to individual menu components, it gets fired whenever a component loses focus. You only want it to get fired when the *window* loses focus, so add it to the window instead.</strike>

`main.addWindowFocusListener(f1);`

should fix your problem.